Boolean Objects show random color where sliced
Okay, I hae been dealing with this probelm since starting this project. I have been doing multiple floor plan layouts for a client and to see the floor plan better, I am using booleans to control the height of some interior walls, windows and doors. I did this because some areas are being cut but there are cases that they don't need to be. Anyway, this issue is the color that renders where the object is being cut. I have tried many things that I know of to fix it but nothing seems to fix it. Like some doors are being showing white like the material that is set for that object, but others will show black. Sometimes I can get it to go away if I shade flat and switch between Keep sharp edges and not, but obviously this hasn't been a permenant solution.
What am I missing here!? I have an image attached as an example of some windows. I used the Alt Shift copy mode so they are linked, and the boolean modifyer is the same between the two. Yet they are different. The right side is the correct look I want. Has anyone run into this problem? I can't share my file due to copyright issues but if there is more information you need let me know.


How to upload a blend file on BSE - good practices and advice

This question seems misleading, because it appears to frame the issue as being a material or or shading problem, when in fact I suspect this is a geometric problem caused by failed booleans

To find out what exactly is going on there we might need the file, but since you cannot upload it I can at least tell you how the materials work on Boolean operations, maybe this already explains a bit that might be of use.
Let's say I have a window frame. It has a white material in material slot 0 and a purple material in slot 1. The purple material is not used on the frame though. The windows are a separate object with a single glass material.
The frame and its materials:

The glass object with its material:

And then I have a cuboid object which will be used as a cutter in Boolean modifiers on the frame and the windows to cut off the top half. It has 3 materials: a cyan one in slot 0, green in slot 1 and yellow in slot 2:

Now I add the Boolean modifiers to the frame and the glass. With the Solver in the modifier set to Exact you can choose between two Materials settings: Index Based or Transfer. The one in your screenshot is set to Index Based which is the default, but I'll show both here.
The frame will use Index Based, the glass Transfer. So if I now enable the modifiers and hide the cutter so that we can see the top of the cut it looks like this:

The reasons for this are the following:
First of all, the glass material has the modifier set to Transfer. This means the new faces created at the top inherit the material of the cutting object in respective area, so the left side is cyan, the middle part is green and the right side is yellow. Even though the windows only had a single glass material, if you would apply the modifier now, the new windows will have all four materials, the glass and the colors of the cutter.
A different method works on the frame: Index Based means, the newly created faces will get the material with the same slot index as the materials on the cutter object in the respective areas. So, the left side is the cutter's slot 0, the middle part is slot 1 and the right side should be slot 2. But since the frame object only has a slot 0 and 1, it will fall back to slot 0. This would also happen if there was a third slot on the frame object but it was empty without any material. Applying the modifier will not add any materials to the frame since it only uses its already existing materials.
Further information on how the new faces will be colored regarding a cutter object with no material slots or empty slots (empty slots meaning there is a slot but it has no material):
Transfer

If the cutter has an empty slot 1 for example, the new face would get the material of slot 1 on the original object. If the original slot is empty or does not exist, the faces get the material of the original object's slot 0.

If the cutter object has only a single empty slot or no slot at all, the new faces get the material from the original object's slot 0, no matter if this material is assigned to any other original face or not.


Index Based

If the cutter has a slot index that does not exist on the original object, the new faces created there get the material from the original object's slot 0.

If a slot of the cutter object exists on the original object but it is empty, the new faces get the material in the original object's slot 0.

If the cutter object has only a single empty slot or no slots at all, the new faces will get the material in slot 0 of the original object - no matter if this material is assigned to any other original face or not.


This sounds very similar for both modes and it is, but the major difference of course is, the Transfer method introduces new materials to the original object while the Index Based metohd only uses the materials present on the original object. And due to this difference they also deal a little bit differently with empty or non-existing slots on either the cutter or original object.
As I said in the beginning, to find out what exactly is going on in your model it would have been good to upload it. But here an example scenario what could cause the difference between the white and black cut faces when using the Index Based method:
Your cutter object does not have any material at all. Which means, the new faces at the cut get the material in slot 0 of the original object. If the object has a black and a white material and one object has the white in slot 0 and the other has the black in slot 0, then the first one will show white at the cut and the second will show black - no matter if the faces are all black using the same material.
Like in the following image: both windows look exactly the same, they have a white frame and the weather strip is black. But the left window has the white material in slot 0, the right window has the black material in slot 0. The cutter has no material slots at all, which means the new faces automatically get slot 0 assigned, regardless of their surrounding geometry:

In this case the simple solution could be to move the slot with the material which you want to show up at the cut to the top of the list by using the arrow/triangle buttons to the right. Now the thing is, if you simply duplicate windows they should not have different orders of materials slots. So once again, this is all guess work without knowing the real objects. Another problem could be simply Z-fighting, if there are faces overlapping each other. But then this should not occur in EEVEE or the Material Preview mode, just with Cycles.

That was just what I needed to know about the boolean modifier! Because the geometry I am using for the boolean to cut away the ojects has no material, I just switched the modifier to transfer. That fixed the issue I have been dealing with. Thank you!
